# Attempting to connect to Firebird 2.5 database, getting "-service path\database.FDB:service_mgr" is not defined

Tags: firebird

I'm trying to run a trace using

```
fbtracemgr -SE "localhost:C:\Users\user1\Desktop\db.FDB:service_mgr" -user SYSDBA -password masterkey -start -name "to" -config "C:\Users\user1\traceparameter.conf" > c:\Users\user1\dboutput.txt

Cannot attach to services manager
-service C:\Users\user1\Desktop\db.FDB:service_mgr is not defined
```

Any ideas why this might be?!

I've also tried without `:service_mgr` and I get the same result.

If I refer to a non existing database (used a random db.FDB filename) I get the same result, so it seems to not be related to the db itself at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `-SE localhost:service_mgr` or - local only - `-SE service_mgr`. The `service_mgr` specifies you connect to the "Service Manager" of Firebird, not to a specific database. In other words, the database name does not belong in that connection string.

See also [Audit and Trace Services in Firebird 2.5](https://www.ibphoenix.com/articles/art-00000003).